# Insert category products inside accordion with a function

Tags: php, function, while-loop, bootstrap-4, accordion

So I have an accordion, within that accordion I have another inner accordion for all the different kinds of categories which I get through a while loop. But the problem starts when I to insert the products inside a category.

All products get spit out outside of the accordion.

[Like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HUCIo.png)

I have a function that loops through all categories and creates an accordion, and inside the accordion body of the category I call another function which gives me the products, it looks like this:

function getCategories() {
    global $connection;

```
$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM categories");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $categoryTitle = $row['cat_title'];
    $catId = $row['cat_id'];
    $products = accordionCategoryProducts($catId);

    $categories = "<div class='card mb-2'>
                      <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                        <h5 class='mb-0'>
                          <div href='#category$catId' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                            <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>$categoryTitle
                          </div>
                          <div class='float-right'>
                          <a href='category.php?id=$catId'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                        </h5> 
                      </div>

                      <div id='category$catId' class='collapse'>
                        <div class='card-body'>
                            <div class='list-group-item'>
                                $products
                            </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>";

    echo $categories;
}
```

}

```
function accordionCategoryProducts($id) {
global $connection;

$query = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_category_id='$id'");
$numRows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

if($numRows > 0) {
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $products = "<li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=".$row['id']."'><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> ".$row['title']."</a>
            </li>";
            echo $products;

   }
}
```

}

```
 <div class="col-lg-12">
  <div id="accordion">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-header text-white cat_header">
        <h5 class="mb-0">
          <div href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
            <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> <?php echo CAT_NAV; ?>
          </div>
        </h5> 
      </div>

      <!-- First collapsed accordion -->
      <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show">
        <div class="card-body">

            <div class="accordion-inner" id="accordion-inner">

                <?php getCategories(); ?>

            </div>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>




</div>
```

But when I hardcode some html it goes to its rightful place.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7068.png)
Why is $products outside of the accordion, but when I type a 'random string' its inside, what is causing this behavior?
Can someone point me to the right direction?

source code:

```
<section id="category_nav" class="py-5 bg-light">



  <div class=container>
    <div class="row" id="cat_list">
      <div class="info-header mb-5 ml-3">
          <h1 class="text-primary pb-3">
            Browse through all Categories!
          </h1>
          <p class="lead pb-3">
              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
              tempor incididunt ut labore
          </p>
        </div>

          <!-- ACCORDION -->
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div id="accordion">
          <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header text-white cat_header">
              <h5 class="mb-0">
                <div href="#collapse1" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion">
                  <i class="fas fa-arrow-circle-down"></i> Categories                </div>
              </h5> 
            </div>

            <!-- First collapsed accordion -->
            <div id="collapse1" class="collapse show">
              <div class="card-body">

                  <div class="accordion-inner" id="accordion-inner">

                      <li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=1><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Arkouda</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=2><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Yo</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=20><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Paroutsia</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=21><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Hello</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=41><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Title</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category4' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Ρούχα
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=4'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category4' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=9><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Paroutsia</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=10><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Hello</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=13><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Yo</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=30><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=31><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=32><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=33><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=34><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=35><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=36><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=37><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=38><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> asdasd</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category5' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Παπούτσια
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=5'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category5' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=4><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Τέντες</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=12><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Arkouda</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=23><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Producto</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category6' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Γάντια
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=6'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category6' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=5><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Φιδι</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category9' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Επικαλαμίδες
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=9'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category9' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=11><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Product</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=14><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Γάντια</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=22><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Product</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category10' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Μασελάκι
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=10'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category10' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=3><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Γάντια</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=6><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Καφες</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=15><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Τέντες</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=17><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Καφες</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category11' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Κατηγορια 1
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=11'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category11' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=7><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Dunno</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=16><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Φιδι</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=18><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Dunno</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category12' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Λάμπες
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=12'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category12' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=8><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Car</a>
            </li><li class='list-group'>
                    <a href='item.php?id=19><i class='fas fa-caret-right'></i> Car</a>
            </li><div class='card mb-2'>
                          <div class='card-header mb-0' style='background-color: #fff;''>
                            <h5 class='mb-0'>
                              <div href='#category13' data-toggle='collapse' data-parent='#accordion-inner' style='cursor:pointer;' class='d-inline'>
                                <i class='far fa-caret-square-right'></i>Cars
                              </div>
                              <div class='float-right'>
                              <a href='category.php?id=13'><button class='btn btn-sm float-right cat-btn'><i class='fas fa-angle-right'></i> Go to page</button></a></div>
                            </h5> 
                          </div>

                          <div id='category13' class='collapse'>
                            <div class='card-body'>
                                <div class='list-group-item'>

                                </div>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                  </div>


              </div>
            </div>
          </div>



        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>

</section>
```

Comment: You did not mention, that you use [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/). You may want to rewrite your question without PHP but with the Bootstrap version and more info about any other CSS library you use? Because IMO it boils down to an HTML/CSS problem, provided that your [data is clean](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).

Comment: I'm not sure if its a html/css problem because if I hardcore some <li's they get printed with no problems inside the inner-accordion with no problems.

Comment: Give us the HTML source code ("view source" in most browsers) of your hard coded and the dynamically generated version. Then we can compare and help you. Did you try [escaping](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) your data?

Comment: Okay done, what do you mean by escaping my data?